# Fixing the photo position in ModernCV

Tags: positioning, titles, moderncv

I used an offset of 2.5cm  for the title and now I want to move the photo 2.5cm more to the left.

How can I get that done?

My MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme[grey]{classic}                % idem
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[utf8x]{luainputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage[scale=0.8]{geometry}
\recomputelengths  % required when changes are made to page layout lengths
\fancyfoot{} % clear all footer fields
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[RE,LO]{\footnotesize } % other info in "inner" position of footer line
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\newcommand\AtPageUpperMyleft[1]{\AtPageUpperLeft{%
 \put(\LenToUnit{2.1cm},\LenToUnit{-6.5cm}){#1}%
 }}%

\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{%
\AtPageUpperMyleft{\fboxsep1.5pt
    %\fcolorbox{gray}{white}%
{\includegraphics[width=60pt,height=3cm,keepaspectratio]{qrdummy.png}}}
}
\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}
\title{Curriculum Vitae}
\photo[84pt]{squirrel.jpg}
\begin{document}
%\vspace{-15cm} % useless?
\hspace{2.5cm}
\maketitle
\vspace{-10mm}
\section{Info}
\cvcomputer
{\textbf{*}}{\small date of birth, City (Country)\normalsize}
{\faFlag{}}{\small Nationality\normalsize}

\section{Desired Employment and Current Skills}
\cvline{}{\Large Computer Guy}
\cvline{}{\small Wow, look at my skills!}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to find the correct location inside `\makecvtitle` and patch it using `etoolbox`. [`moderncv`](http://ctan.org/pkg/moderncv) doesn't provide a hook explicitly for this kind of adjustment.

The following patch adjusts for the placement:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\makecvtitle}% <cmd>
  {\usebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}\\[2.5em]}% <search>
  {\hspace*{-2.5cm}\usebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}\\[2.5em]}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
```

[image]